# SWI Prolog stuck with odd behavior

Tags: prolog

So here is the thing.I am trying to make a sort of "perfect match" program in prolog.
You give it a couple and each individual has some "characteristics".The program is supposed
to return possible problems in future marriage depending on those characteristics.But when I try to do that and things get complicated I get this problem:

```
1 ?- marriage_problems(Couple).
Wifename(sharon,marsh)
Husbandname(randy,marsh)
Possible problem:Wife is lazy while husband is demanding.Not matching.
true ;
Possible problem: Wife is agressive while husband is sensitive.Not matching.
true ;
Possible problem: Wife is sensitive while husband is agressive.Not matching.
true ;
Possible problem: Wife is sensitive while husband is agressive.Not matching.
true ;
Possible problem: Wife is sensitive while husband is agressive.Not matching.
true ;
Possible problem: Wife is sensitive while husband is agressive.Not matching.
true
```

It never stops anwsering wife is sensitive while husband is..Not matching.And it's also wrong.And here is the code:

```
couple(wife(name(sharon,marsh),char(economical([stingy,lazy]),sexual([agressive]))),
   husband(name(randy,marsh),char(economical([demanding,wasteful]),sexual([sensitive])))).



marriage_problems(Couple):- couple(wife(Wname,char(economical(W_eco),sexual(W_sex))),
                                   husband(Hname,char(economical(H_eco),sexual(H_sex)))),
                                   write('Wife'),write(Wname),nl,
                                   write('Husband'),write(Hname),nl,
                                   marriage_economical_problems(W_eco,H_eco);
                                   marriage_sexual_problems(W_sex,H_sex).





marriage_economical_problems(W_eco,H_eco):-              couple(wife(_,char(economical(W_eco),_)),husband(_,char(economical(H_eco),_))),
                                                         member(demanding,W_eco),
                                                         member(lazy,H_eco),
                                                         W_pr=demanding,
                                                         H_pr=lazy,
                                                         write('Possible problem:Wife is '),write(W_pr),write(' while husband is '),
                                                         write(H_pr),write('.Not matching.'),nl;
                                                         member(lazy,W_eco),
                                                         member(demanding,H_eco),
                                                         W_pr=lazy,
                                                         H_pr=demanding,
                                                         write('Possible problem:Wife is '),write(W_pr),write(' while husband is '),
                                                         write(H_pr),write('.Not matching.'),nl.


marriage_sexual_problems(W_sex,H_sex):-             couple(wife(_,char(_,sexual(W_sex))),husband(_,char(_,sexual(H_sex)))),
                                                    member(agressive,W_sex),
                                                    member(sensitive,H_sex),
                                                    W_pr=agressive,
                                                    H_pr=sensitive,
                                                    write('Possible problem: Wife is '),write(W_pr),write(' while husband is '),
                                                    write(H_pr),write('.Not matching.'),nl;
                                                    member(sensitive,W_sex),
                                                    member(agressive,H_sex),
                                                    W_pr=sensitive,
                                                    H_pr=agressive,
                                                    write('Possible problem: Wife is '),write(W_pr),write(' while husband is '),
                                                    write(H_pr),write('.Not matching.'),nl.
```

And this oddly enough works:

```
1 ?- marriage_problems(Couple).
Wifename(sharon,marsh)
Husbandname(randy,marsh)
Possible problem:Wife is lazy while husband is demanding.Not matching.
true ;
Possible problem: Wife is agressive while husband is sensitive.Not matching.
true.
```

code:

```
couple(wife(name(sharon,marsh),char(economical([stingy,lazy]),sexual([agressive]))),
       husband(name(randy,marsh),char(economical([demanding,wasteful]),sexual([sensitive])))).



marriage_problems(Couple):- couple(wife(Wname,char(economical(W_eco),sexual(W_sex))),
                                   husband(Hname,char(economical(H_eco),sexual(H_sex)))),
                                   write('Wife'),write(Wname),nl,
                                   write('Husband'),write(Hname),nl,
                                   marriage_economical_problems(W_eco,H_eco);
                                   marriage_sexual_problems(W_sex,H_sex).





marriage_economical_problems(W_eco,H_eco):-              couple(wife(_,char(economical(W_eco),_,_,_)),husband(_,char(economical(H_eco),_,_,_))),
                                                         member(demanding,W_eco),
                                                         member(lazy,H_eco),
                                                         W_pr=demanding,
                                                         H_pr=lazy,
                                                         write('Possible problem:Wife is '),write(W_pr),write(' while husband is '),
                                                         write(H_pr),write('.Not matching.'),nl;
                                                         member(lazy,W_eco),
                                                         member(demanding,H_eco),
                                                         W_pr=lazy,
                                                         H_pr=demanding,
                                                         write('Possible problem:Wife is '),write(W_pr),write(' while husband is '),
                                                         write(H_pr),write('.Not matching.'),nl.


marriage_sexual_problems(W_sex,H_sex):-             couple(wife(_,char(_,sexual(W_sex))),husband(_,char(_,sexual(H_sex)))),
                                                    member(agressive,W_sex),
                                                    member(sensitive,H_sex),
                                                    W_pr=agressive,
                                                    H_pr=sensitive,
                                                    write('Possible problem: Wife is '),write(W_pr),write(' while husband is '),
                                                    write(H_pr),write('.Not matching.'),nl.
```

So when it gets more complicated it does not work for some reason..
I really can't understand what's going on.I am only a couple of months familiar with 
prolog.I've been playing with this problem a few days myself with no luck.But now
I've run out of time and I need to get things done.Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm so tempted to say it's because not even computers can understand the baffling complexities of marriage and human courtship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are misusing the OR operator (;)/2, you probably meant

```
marriage_problems(Couple):- couple(wife(Wname,char(economical(W_eco),sexual(W_sex))),
                                   husband(Hname,char(economical(H_eco),sexual(H_sex)))),
                                   write('Wife'),write(Wname),nl,
                                   write('Husband'),write(Hname),nl,
                                   ( marriage_economical_problems(W_eco,H_eco);
                                     marriage_sexual_problems(W_sex,H_sex) ).
```

without the parens, W_sex and H_sex are unbound when calling marriage_sexual_problems/2.
SWI-Prolog is able to signal the symptom:

```
Warning: /home/carlo/prolog/so.pl:81:
    Singleton variable in branch: W_sex
    Singleton variable in branch: H_sex
Warning: /home/carlo/prolog/so.pl:81:
    Singleton variables: [Couple]
```

Also note that Couple is useless...

Comment: Thank you for your anwser.It solved my problem.As I said I am very new to prolog and I don't quite get it's logic yet.I don't really understand why parens are needed even now.. But yea it works so thanks. Also I want to use Couple because later I'll be entering different couples with different "chars" through prolog's command prompt but that seems impossible too right now ugh.

Comment: @CapelliC, as an aside on precedence, one thing I puzzle over a little is that `*` is higher precedence than `+`, so `X is 2 + 3 * 4` yields `X = 14` (the `*` is taken first since it's higher precedence). However, `;` is higher precedence than `,`, yet `false, true ; true` and `true ; true, false` each result in `true`, meaning Prolog takes the `,` first in each case. I would have that that meant `,` was higher precedence. Where's the error in my thinking?

Comment: @lurker: this [table](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=op/3) gives (+)/2 precedence 500, while (\*)/2 has 400... seems all right. I think the word *precedence* could be misleading, effectively when I initially posted the answer, I told (wronlgy) that ; has lower precedence than ,

Comment: You puzzled me now lol. So does prolog give priority to and(,) or or(;)?

Comment: @DieCriminal, the `,` (AND) does indeed take "priority" over `;` (OR), so you need the parentheses, as CapelliC indicated. Our discussion is over the word precedence. CapelliC, this [Learn Prolog Now link](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse40) says, the higher the number, the greater the precedence, which is where my confusion started. I thought higher precedence meant it takes priority, which means their statement would be incorrect.